# Printing string inside the Custom column in jspdf autotable

Tags: javascript, string, jspdf-autotable

I'm printing data inside a pdf using `jspdf-autotable`. I have two types of strings:

1. String
2. (5 white Space) + String

If the Type(2) string is too long it means that the remaining part of the string will be printed on the next line (as I'm using the the linebreak option). What I'm expecting is that the the remaining string, which is printed on the next line, should be printed with the same 5 white space as the first. But it prints without any white space. Note that I'm not using html, only javascript and jspdf. How can I achive the same indentation (same amount of white space) on each new line?

Actual output:

```
    Trees are in proper shape and labeled
appropriately
```

What I want:

```
  Trees are in proper shape and labeled
  appropriately
```

Comment: So you want `Trees` and `appropriately` to have the same two space indentation (looks like that in the example you gave)? This instead of having `Trees` have five spaces indentation and `appropriately` having zero.

Comment: Yes ...Yes....You are absolutely  right .

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

The first is the `cellPadding` option. It will make the same horizontal space on both side of the cell.

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
doc.autoTable(columns, data, {
    styles: {cellPadding: 10}
});
return doc;
```

The other option is to use the `drawCell` hook and decide where to print the cell content yourself. I have not tested this, but should work.

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
doc.autoTable(columns, data, {
    drawCell: function (cell, data) {
        if (cell.dataKey === "email") {
            cell.x += 20;
        }
    }
});
return doc;
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what didn't work? And is my edit of your question correct?

Comment: Okey..After sometime i will edit my code and show you what was happened.